# About conjuration and necromancy, then

Tags: discussion, tags

So we have [a discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7793/4563) about [enchantment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enchantment), and one of the sources of confusion is the assumption that [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration) and [necromancy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/necromancy) refer to the D&D spell schools of those names. Meanwhile, [necromancy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/necromancy) has tag info that focuses on raising the dead—which does not cover the entirety of the D&D school of Necromancy—and [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration) has no tag info at all, but is tagged on questions about summoning a creature or object, which is what the word means.

Notably, this means that things that fall in these D&D schools—say, curses, or healing, or teleportation—shouldn’t actually get these tags, but rather [curses](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curses) or [healing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healing) or [teleportation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teleportation).

(On the other hand, we also have [divination](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divination) and [illusion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illusion)—the latter of which is also defined as a type of spell rather than  a reference to a D&D spell school—, but those seem, to me, to be less confusing, less likely to be assumed to refer to the spell schools, and in any event those D&D schools lack “surprising” effects.)

Does this mean we should rename [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration) and [necromancy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/necromancy), to be clearer that they refer to a specific sort of effect that is a sub-set of what falls under those D&D spell schools? Say, [summoning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summoning) (which already exists anyway, and is on way more questions than [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration)) and [undead-animation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undead-animation) or something. Or should we just rely on the tag info to clarify, and appropriate moderation to correct mistakes where they occur?

These seem far less dire than [enchantment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enchantment) to me, but there was enough discussion of them in the other question that I thought the issue should be raised. Particularly [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration), where [summoning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summoning) and [teleportation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teleportation) (and [healing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healing), at least in some editions of D&D) already exist and are much bigger, and it’s unclear what questions should be tagged [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration) instead of one of those. “Conjuration” is not necessarily the first term most people think of for these effects, except perhaps coming from a D&D background. “Necromancy,” on the other hand, probably *is* the first word most think of when it comes to animating the undead (even if the word’s origin is as a form of divination performed with dead animals).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally, I would leave [necromancy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/necromancy) alone, but I probably would re-tag things tagged [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration) with [summoning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summoning); the latter’s the bigger tag, and probably the more common name for those effects, and it seems to apply to each of the questions currently tagged [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration). I am undecided on the issue of synonyms here, though.

UPDATE: [Conjuration (mostly) spirited away](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7818/4563)

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to write. When I saw [conjuration] created this was exactly what I thought, but took a wait-and-see approach. If the result of that wait is that it's causing confusion about what our tags are fundamentally for, its time is up.