# Conjuration spirited away

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

So per [the discussion about conjuration and necromancy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7801/4563), [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration) has been <s>mostly</s> removed from questions.

It was removed from each of the following, and replaced with [summoning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summoning):

- [Does a dagger summoned by Minor Conjuration overcome resistances?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117153/4563)
- [Can I conjure a dagger or dart in my offhand and use bonus action to attack with it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117150/4563)
- [Does a “Minor Conjuration” object contain details of the original even if the caster did not see those details?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112254/4563)
- [Can “Minor Conjuration” create a physical key?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112222/4563)
- [What exactly is the difference between conjure animals and woodland beings?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/96180/4563)
- [When you lose control of Conjure Elemental, is it still hostile towards your enemies or just you?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95241/4563)
- [Do you have to be the ritual leader when creating an ally spirit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79610/4563)
- [Could you replicate a spell book using minor conjuration?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79578/4563)
- [How fragile are Minor Conjurations?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67404/4563)
- [What happens if I Minor Conjuration an object I have seen - but didn't know it was magical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67918/4563) (also added [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items))
- [Can conjured creatures bring back something (objects or creatures)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55502/4563)
- [Limitations on the Conjurer's Minor Conjuration ability](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47885/4563)
- [Do conjurations still appear if you miss?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28835/4563)
- [Do the Onyx Dog's temporary hit points disappear when the party takes a short rest?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14866/4563)

It was also removed from the following, which already had [summoning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summoning):

- [Losing concentration on Conjure Elemental if you summon an Invisible Stalker?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74278/4563)

<s>There are two remaining questions in [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration):</s>

- [Flaming Sphere AOE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63880/4563)—Literally the only place in this question that the text “conjur” appears is in the [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration) tag. While *flaming sphere* is a Conjuration spell, its status as a conjuration has nothing to do with the question. I suggest just removing it altogether.

  On the other hand, the [4e question about conjurations appearing if you miss](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28835/4563), which is about *Bigby’s icy grasp*, may provide precedent for treating non-creature/non-object conjurations as [summoning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summoning). At all, the flaming sphere persists and you can move it around, which does overlap some with summoning a creature.
- [My Wizard is conjuring a piece of the sun. How will this affect my setting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100751/4563)—I would support calling this [summoning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summoning) despite it only being a piece of the sun, but it’s different enough that I wanted to highlight it before I touched it.

These two remaining questions have been dealt with per [doppelgreener’s answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7820/4563), and [conjuration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjuration) is gone!

Comment: @doppelgreener I went ahead and did it, so feel free to add [[tag:status-completed]] on there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Flaming Sphere AOE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63880/4563) — I don't think this needs the conjuration or summoning tags.

- The question isn't materially about summoning, it's asking about a fireball that happens to *get* summoned. If I asked about how to make a weapon attack with my axe, that I happened to summon from over there a minute ago, the question still wouldn't be a summoning question, it would be a weapon attack question.
- From what I understand of the discussion in [About conjuration and necromancy, then](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7801/about-conjuration-and-necromancy-then) and [New enchantment tag, not sure about this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/new-enchantment-tag-not-sure-about-this), tagging by what school a spell happens to belong in isn't useful.

We tag [necromancy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/necromancy) questions that are about the activity of raising undead & doing similar hijinks: we don't tag a healing spell with [necromancy] just because it's in the necromancy school. We should tag [summoning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summoning) questions if and when the question is materially about summoning a thing.

---

[My Wizard is conjuring a piece of the sun. How will this affect my setting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100751/my-wizard-is-conjuring-a-piece-of-the-sun-how-will-this-affect-my-setting) — should have the [summoning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summoning) tag. He's summoning a piece of the sun. He scried its location (and got his eyes fixed afterwards, phew), and wants to make it wink out of existence over there and wink into existence over here. That's [summoning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summoning), and it's materially about the activity of doing that. (The answers dive into "I don't think that counts for the summoning spell you're using" territory.) It's also materially about other things, like what kind of total havoc and/or burnination this is going to unleash.

---

Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: I had exactly these thoughts myself, yes. Just wanted to highlight edge cases before doing things unilaterally.