# Break [Enchantment] cast

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

About implementing decisions made about [enchantment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enchantment), per [New enchantment tag, not sure about this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7793/4563) (A: Yes, it’s an issue and needs to go away.), [Should charmed be synonymized with mind-control?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7812/4563) (A: No.), and [Should Enchantment be blacklisted as a tag name, or synonymized with another tag?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7809/4563) (A: No.).

Comment: @doppelgreener I believe [tag:status-completed] may also be appropriate here. At the very least, all the questions are dealt with, though people may want to revisit some of the choices I made.

Comment: Right you are, added that one too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [mind-control](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mind-control) had been added to a question already, but its tag info had not been created. I did so:

> > Use this tag for questions about effects that grant the user mental control over another target, or how targets that are controlled are supposed to behave. For other forms of mental manipulation that do not give the user control, see related tags.
>
> Mind control is the ability to take over someone else's mind and control their actions. Questions in this tag may be about how to gain that control, how the control works, or what lingering side-effects there may be after the control is ended.
>
> This tag is not for all forms of mental manipulation. For other forms of mental manipulation, consider appropriate specific tags like [charmed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charmed) or [fear](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fear).

Could be better, I’m sure, but it gets across the ideas that came out of the discussion for synonymizing [charmed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charmed) with [mind-control](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mind-control).

Second, the following questions have been edited to conform to the meta decisions.

This question has had [enchantment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enchantment) removed without replacement:

- [Does Staff of Sleep and Charm's property work offhand?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90492/4563) (the item is used for charming, but the question is solely about whether or not the item works in a particular circumstance, not about the things you do with it)
- [Does the caster of an enchantment spell always know if the spell worked or failed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103435/4563) (really just about spell mechanics in general, already had [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells))
- [Break Enchantment v. Feeblemind](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83348/4563) (about the interaction of two spells, already has [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells))

This question lost [enchantment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enchantment), and gained [class-features](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-features)

- [Can a School of Enchantment Wizard use Instinctive charm against spell attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68839/4563)

These questions have had [enchantment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enchantment) replaced with [charmed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charmed):

- [When does a target know it's under the effects of a charm/enchantment spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114701/4563)
- [Do any charm spells stop working when the caster is in an Antimagic Field?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93415/4563) (arguably not really about charming itself so much as various magic mechanics, but the question does basically want to know if charms have a special exception)
- [Is Charm Person obvious?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76286/4563)
- [How do enchantment spells work with V/S components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44775/4563) (this one is debatable; it’s basically asking whether the D&D spell school Enchantment has a special exception, but I went with [charmed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charmed) because it seems most relevant with enchantments that are trying to be subtle)

These question had [enchantment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enchantment) replaced with [mind-control](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mind-control):

- [Does Protection from Evil protect you from Suggestion?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63463/4563)
- [Is Dominate Person's telepathic link one-way or two-way?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113554/4563)
- [What happens when you cast dominate person on yourself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45271/4563)
- [Do you remember what happened during Dominate Person?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30427/4563)
- [What's a Dominate Person between allies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/22494/4563)

This question replaced [enchantment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enchantment) with [mind-control](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mind-control), and actually lost [charmed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charmed) because despite that keyword appearing in the question, the question focuses solely on *dominate person* (that mention of charm was also removed from the question body).

- [Can Dominated person/creature which receive no command remember they are being dominated?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113553/4563)

This question had [enchantment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enchantment) replaced with [charmed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charmed)[mind-control](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mind-control), and also lost [conditions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditions) in order to make room:

- [Do charmed people realise they were charmed after the end of the spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76729/4563) (despite the title, the question asks about both *charm person* and *dominate person*)

And with those, [enchantment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enchantment) no longer has any questions.